# AWS S3 with Express.JS Async issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I am new to Express and Amazon aws S3. I am developing an app to handle forms. The front end is deployed on Netlify and gets the form data. Backend express.js is deployed on Render.com. The raw form is on AWS s3 storage. With a POST request, Backend gets an instance of the raw form from AWS, fills the form and saves it back into an output folder on AWS. Then the user can press a download button for a GET request on frontend, so the backend can get a copy of the prepared form from AWS.

The problem is that I am getting a 200 status for my POST request before the prepared form is available on aws. The 200 response causes my download button to show up early, so the user has to click it a few times for the download to start!

Here is the brief snippets to show the work flow:

Backend Express API:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const formHandler = require("./formHandler");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// FORM PREPARATION
app.post("/form", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const formData = await req.body;

    await formHandler(formData);
    res.status(200).json({
      satus: "PDF created.",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

// DOWNLOAD FORM
app.get("/form/download/:folderName", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const getObjectParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
      Key: 'output/preparedForm.pdf',
    };
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const s3Stream = s3.getObject(getObjectParams).createReadStream();

    s3Stream.on("error", (err) => {
      console.error("Error downloading file from S3:", err);
      res.status(500).send("Error downloading file");
    });

    // Pipe the S3 object data to the Express response
    s3Stream.pipe(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server running on port ${port}`);
});
module.exports = app;
```

**Form handling module that modifies and saves the form:**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const { PDFDocument } = require("pdf-lib");

const formHandler = async (formData) => {
  try {
    // Create an S3 instance
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const downloadParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
      Key: "forms/rawForm.pdf",
    };

    s3.getObject(downloadParams, (err, form) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error downloading PDF form from S3:", err);
      } else {
        // 'data.Body' contains the PDF form content
        const pdfFormBuffer = form.Body;

        // Proceed to fill out the form
        fillOutPDFForm(pdfFormBuffer, formData);
      }
    });

    const fillOutPDFForm = async (pdfFormBuffer, formData) => {
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfFormBuffer);
      const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
      //HERE GOES THE FORM FILLING BUSINESS LOGIC

      // Serialize the modified PDF
      const modifiedPdfBuffer = await pdfDoc.save();

      // Save the modified PDF back to Amazon S3
      saveModifiedPDFToS3(modifiedPdfBuffer);
    };

    // UPLOADING THE PREPARED FORM TO AWS S3
    const saveModifiedPDFToS3 = async (modifiedPdfBuffer) => {
      // Convert modifiedPdfBuffer to a Buffer
      const bufferData = Buffer.from(modifiedPdfBuffer);

      const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
        Key: "output/preparedForm.pdf",
        Body: bufferData, // Use the converted Buffer
      };

      try {
        const storePDF = await s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading modified PDF to S3:", error);
      }
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

module.exports = formHandler;
```

Comment: Nothing in your async code waits for the `getObject()` to complete so `formHandler` completes almost immediately. Use the promise version and await the result (see the duplicate post)